# Views entity reference field filtering results based on permissions but not overridable

Tags: entities

I have created an entity reference field on a node type and it references entities of the Profile type, my Profile bundle is called 'Staff profile'.

I want to allow certain users to see staff profiles of other users in this entity reference field, but I don't want them to see ALL users staff profiles.

If a user has the permission "Staff: View any profiles" then they can see EVERY profile in this entity reference field, once I remove this they can only see their own - this is as expected and does seem to indicate my issue is with permissions.

So I am trying to allow this access to certain profiles for certain users in a 'my_module_profile_access' function. And this is working in that if I try to view a profile directly i.e. I go to /profile/123 (with a user whom I have allowed access to view the profile) it works fine, it works as expected.

However this behaviour does not repeat itself when I try to use the entity reference field, which makes me suspect there is some other permissions interfering here?

For what it is worth my hook_entity_access function looks something like this -

```
function my_module_profile_access(Profile $profile, $op, $account) {
  $profileOwner = $profile->getOwner();
  
  if ($account->id() == '2' && $profileOwner->id() == '123') {
      return AccessResult::allowed()->cachePerUser()->addCacheableDependency($profile);
  }
  // No opinion.
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Comment: Try checking these modules out: (Reference Access)[https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_access], (Permissions by field)[https://www.drupal.org/project/pbf], (Access by Reference)[https://www.drupal.org/project/access_by_ref].

Comment: Can't see any difference to what I am doing, I'm out of ideas unless someone else chimes in